# Locate Identity Errors on Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-identity

I've created an MVC project and added the functionality which allows users to log in with 3rd party login providers (Twitter, Google, Facebook and Microsoft). I kept receiving an error so i added a breakpoint and a string[] of Errors showed the error "A user with that external login already exists.". To my understanding, this is an identity error, however, I'm unable to find where this string[] is. A friend told me to look at resource.resx file but that is nowhere to be found in my solution. Any help on where I can find the errors?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ManageLogins", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }
        var result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), loginInfo.Login);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ManageLogins");
        }
        else
        {
            var errorMessage = result.Errors.First();
            if (errorMessage.Equals("A user with that external login already exists.", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                 return RedirectToAction("ManageLogins", new { Message = ManageMessageId.EmailExists });
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ManageLogins", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
            }
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: the error is pretty clear. you are trying to call create user which the user already exists in the DB

Comment: as for the error msg part. you are kinda screwed. Those strings are hard coded in the identity framework. Your only bet is to do something similar to yours and pray they don't change the text in future update

Comment: Please [edit] the title to be more indicative of what your question is about. Right now it looks like a combination of tags rather than an actual question. See [ask] for tips.